# PIP: Cant install dependencies from builded poetry wheel if pyproject.toml contains deps from file

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, python-poetry, python-wheel

Im using `poetry` in my project for dependencies, so my `pyproject.toml` contains all my dependencies. My goal is is to build a wheel from the current project and install them in another `virtualenv` using `pip`. But im facing an error:

```
pip._vendor.pkg_resources.RequirementParseError: Invalid URL: artifacts/pp-0.358.0.tar.gz
```

I guess that the problem may be in the relative path, but I don't know how to fix it, because when installing dependencies, this package is taken from the tar.gz file located in this path.

Мой `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "package_name"
version = "0.0.0"
description = ""
readme = "README.md"
packages = [
    {include = "package1"},
    {include = "package2"},
    {include = "package3"},
]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "~3.8"
pp = {file = "artifacts/pp-0.358.0.tar.gz"}
...some other deps
```

To build a wheel im using following command:

```
poetry build --format wheel
```

Installing to another virtualenv with following command:

```
pip3 install /Users/av/Projects/package_name/dist/package_name-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Is it any ways to fix it somehow? If I comment `pp` line in dependencies installation works well.

Comment: What is the expected behavior? That the whole `pp` code be added into the `package_name` wheel file?

Comment: yeah, that i can install wheel package in other virtualenv using pip

Comment: I see. But that is not how this works. The `package_name` wheel only contains the `package_name` code and the instruction that `pp` is a dependency, which means that `pp` should be installed when `package_name` is installed. And the issue is that when you install `package_name` with *pip*, *pip* can not resolve the `artifacts/pp-0.358.0.tar.gz` URL because it is relative to the original location of the `package_name` source code, and *pip* does not know what this original location is. -- It is best to avoid this kind of *path* dependency specifications.

Comment: Yeah, the problem here is that im using same pyproject.toml file for installing dependencies (where i need this pp package) and for building wheel. What can i do in this case then?

Comment: What do you want to do? Publish on PyPI? Publish on a private server? Distribute to work colleagues? Personal use?